# Listen to re-connection request from Bluetooth HID device

Tags: android, bluetooth, hid

I have a Bluetooth HID Keyboard and I would like to achieve the following behavior in my android device (I have control over the OS and the (only) app on the device). This behavior automatically happens in an android phone with Lollipop 5.1 (API Level 21/22), and I need to implement it in my device:

1. Find Bluetooth keyboard and establish a connection (OK)
2. Type with Bluetooth keyboard (OK)
3. Connection is lost either because Bluetooth turned off or device got out of range
4. Bluetooth is turned back on and the device is in range
5. Can't use keyboard because there is no connection (but it's paired)
6. **User presses on keyboard keys (any key) and a connection is immediately established**
7. **Keyboard  is usable**

(I'm missing *6* and *7* in my app)

It's like the keyboard is initiating the connection. How does this happen? On *step 1* the device initiates the connection - how would the keyboard itself initiate a connection and how can I listen to it in my app?

My device is running Gingerbread, API Level 10.

Comment: Just not many people into bluetooth problems on android it seems :). 
Anyways, why not implement an OnButtonPress sort of listener on your keyboard, and once it is pressed your keyboard creates RFcomm connection with your phone? If you have the phone paired with the keyboard, then you should have its address, and a common UUID to use.

Comment: @gedo I don't have control over the keyboard's system. I have control over my device (you called it phone but it's not a phone - but something running android)

Comment: In which case I assume that you created the connection with the app on the device yourself? I.E the "createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord" is a call you make on the device? If that's a case, then why not just create a timer thread, that if disconnected, it would every 3 seconds or so, attempt to connect again using the same method?

Comment: Yes I create the connection with the app. But as instructed by the os team I run a shell command to connect: `hidd --connect <MAC Address>`. And reconnecting using this method requires first manually putting the keyboard in a listening state by pressing some key combination